# Add-on to copy a page element with styles

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, browser-extension

I'm looking for an add-on for any browser that could copy any particular web page element with all it's styles to clipboard to be paste-in and show someone.

The aim is to have an opportunity to quickly share a small part of my big project or to assist in writing an article about this HTML and CSS tricks or to inspect a part of someone's else work.

Any ideas? If no such plugin exist, I'll try to write is by myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably too late. But if anyone out there looking for the same thing, use **SnappySnippet**. It was built by [Konrad Dzwinel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1143495/konrad-dzwinel)

[Firefox Add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-uS/firefox/addon/scratchpad-snippets/)

[Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/snappysnippet/blfngdefapoapkcdibbdkigpeaffgcil)

[More details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911338/tools-to-selectively-copy-htmlcssjs-from-existing-sites#answer-18928130)

It's a great extension.

Comment: Unfortunately can't find SnappySnippet for firefox :( Is there any alternative solution?

Answer (score 2):

Haven't seen anyone mention such an extension and a *quick* search doesn't yield one.  You'll probably have to [build one yourself](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/builder).

The excellent Firebug add-on already collects this information, it may be easier to make [a Firebug plugin](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Firebug_Extensions) to add the push-button convenience.

Note that this question is tagged as Greasemonkey, but Greasemonkey is not the best tool for this job.

Comment: The fact that I'm not missing something obvious is all I needed to know. I'll try to build it myself and write here about my success if any. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the **Web Developer** addon (firefox/chrome)? Not sure if it does exactly what you are asking for, but it displays the source in-page, allowing you to select specific sections of the page/source. You can use this feature and then copy-paste the relevant element you want to work with. That is if I understood your needs. If not, please clarify...

Comment: Not really so. Web Developer, as long as Firebug, let you check and copy HTML OR styles. What I need is one-click tool to copy both HTML AND related CSS same time and probably to wrap it all to a simple page markdown (html, head and body tags).