# How to copy HTML and its associated CSS from any web page

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tools to selectively copy html+css+js from existing sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911338/tools-to-selectively-copy-htmlcssjs-from-existing-sites)

Is there any tool so you can select the HTML part you want to copy and then the tool bring you the CSS rules associated with that HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Have u tired it with FireBug https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/firebug/ ??
https://getfirebug.com/

Comment: I have used it before.I'm now using Chrome's inspector. they are pretty the same. the thing is that can I select html and it automatically brings me all the css rules ready for copying?. I know they both show css but you can't copy it at once.

Comment: @SamiAl-Subhi you can easily copy from chrome's inspector tool just select the code and copy and paste it where you want to paste....... i have tried its working.....