# Tool will help me to get all the css and javascript related with an HTML tag

Tags: php, html, google-chrome-devtools, firebug

I'm working on a project, and my task is to get an external html table identified by #s_table_0 using the php function  `file_get_contents($url)`. and then manually get CSS and JS related with that Tag. I just can't find any trick in 'google chrome developer tools' to do the magic for me, instead of get all the css file and delete what have no relation with that table, and then hardly try to find the related JS.

So,i would like to know if there is any tool or some trick to get only CSS and JAVASCRIPT related with a given tag id.

In a URL like :

> http://www.xxxx.ma/index.php/comp/comp-bpro/classement

i have succeed to get this table using the php function  file_get_contents($url) :

```
<table id="s_table_0" class="tblscss" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
```

I need CSS and JS related with that table.
Thanks in advance

Comment: It's almost impossible to extract JS related to the specific element, see my explanation [here]( https://github.com/kdzwinel/SnappySnippet/issues/20).