# Is there a way to select an HTML node and copy only the CSS for that node?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Would like to duplicate a header navigation menu on a sister site but the css applied to the header is comprised of specific and non-specific styles. Is there an easy way to select just the styles needed to duplicate a chunk of html on a page or is the only way to select each child element at a time and copy and paste the CSS?

```
<header>
 <nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
 </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: This question also has some awesome resources and tools to do something similar. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911338/tools-to-selectively-copy-htmlcssjs-from-existing-sites