# Copy all CSS related to one block (with its children)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools, firebug

I am trying to reuse the parts I already created for a website.

So I open Firebug and inspect the top block container and cycle all inner elements and copy the CSS for each part and put them together, but that´s obviously a long process.

Is there a way to select an element within Firebug or the Chrome Developers Tools to copy all the CSS and HTML from the container to the last inner block?

Comment: You couild try IE Debugger;  press f12 to bring it up, then click on the dom explorer.  When you click on a component on your page, it shows you all inherited and classes  being applied.

Comment: it show for 1 div only I need for this div plus all sub content .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911338/tools-to-selectively-copy-htmlcssjs-from-existing-sites this might help a bit. Though it is dated. Have not looked at it closely

Comment: I take a look at the post its really big some tools may help but I need to test them first to see how clean the code I will get ...

Comment: @Bindrid I check the post and test the tools ... not what I am looking for at all ... they are to copy full website ... the closet one is SnappySnippet  one guy mentioned here as well but it will not work with me at alll ... because it delete the classes I try to reuse my code not patch it with ID ID ID ..

Answer (score 2):

on tool I use SnappySnippet its chrome extension
[image: first select the block] 
[image: get the code]

Comment: thanks ... I see this tool in the post mentioned by Bindrid I am not chrome fan .. I prefer firefox ... but any how I need to test the tool first

Comment: no man not at all .... it conver the classes names to ID's <div id="DIV_1">
 <div id="DIV_2">
  <div id="DIV_3">
   this is one my my sites I copy some block all classes is gone and now its ID's its really useless even I can not use the CSS

Comment: I make my self clear I need to reuse my work and I am copying the PHP / html ... what I will do with #div1 CSS !?