# Embed only used scripts and styles in HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Does anyone know of a tool that can look at a webpage with its styles and scripts and images, and then create an HTML file which has those styles and scripts and images embedded, but **only** the ones which are actually used by that page?

I have a typical "this site is offline for maintenance" page, which is actually an entire website in its own right, based on Bootstrap 3. I want to reduce this whole website into a single file with only the images, CSS and JS required to display the page.

**Update**

Using the typical browser Save File functionality does not achieve what I want, as it firstly does not embed the CSS/JS resources in the page, but saves them in a subfolder and references them from there; and secondly, does not appear to strip out the styles and scripts that are not directly referenced by that page, rather saving the files in their entirety.

Comment: You can File -> Save As complete html from browser, and then you have the full page.

Comment: Which browser are you using that embeds only the script/styles that are used by that page? Chrome and Firefox save the complete files in a sub-folder - they don't embed them, and they don't strip out stuff which isn't in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [SnappySnippet](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/snappysnippet/blfngdefapoapkcdibbdkigpeaffgcil) will help. It extracts the HTML & CSS from an element and sends it to e.g. jsfiddle to review. You'd extract it from the HTML element, should work.

Regrettably, it doesn't do JS, but for a Maintenance page it should work fine.

[Some details from the creator on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18928130/1265817) and [here on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=if5pXoIJ4EU).

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be about as close as I am going to get to a solution. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be able to work with the various Bootstrap sprites, but at least the CSS is picked up properly, so it's a good starting point.