# how to save a page with chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a `Chrome extension`, and an important function of it is: when a new tab created, this extension will "save" the whole web page to the hard disk automatically. Just like the built-in "save as" function of Chrome.

I did not get an answer from google for this topic. Would someone please tell me how to do that. It would be better to offer some examples.

Comment: Like you want to save the whole page as HTML, CSS and JS? Or as an image?

Comment: Yes, exactly. There are some download links in the web page which would send to customers. So I prefer to save and forward the original HTML page, instead of image or pdf.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911338/tools-to-selectively-copy-htmlcssjs-from-existing-sites

Comment: See [chrome.pageCapture](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageCapture) API.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `chrome.pageCapture` API to save the page (along with contents such as image, css, scripts) as MHTML file to disk.

See https://developers.chrome.com/extensions/pageCapture