# Microsoft Edge open all link IE with Microsoft Edge

Tags: internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I have a big problem with the last verison of  Microsoft Edge.
I have a service that only works with Internet Explorer and the latest version of Edge forces you to use Edge. When I open a link or the IE application itself, it closes and runs Edge.

I have found a solution. Erase the files in the folder
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\110.0.1587.57\BHO

The problem is when Edge is updated. I have to delete the files again.
I have to do it on several PCs.

Can I somehow force a link to open in IE and not in Edge?
Thank you very much for your help.

Create a script that deletes the files. The problem is in the permissions and the version. The folder changes with each version.
IE compatibility mode in Edge does not work in the application.

Comment: These [similar](https://superuser.com/questions/1773737/how-do-i-stop-edge-from-taking-over-internet-explorer) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75580262/microsoft-edge-open-all-link-ie-with-microsoft-edge) on superuser.com provide further options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution.
Creating a script in .VBS

```
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 
ie.Visible = True
ie.Navigate "HERE YOUR URL"
```

What this does is to force IE to open with the URL you specify.

Answer (score -1):

The IE11 desktop application is currently retired and out-of-support, and has been permanently disabled since February 14, 2023. [IE Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode) is then recommended for this, particularly when you have several PCs to work with the application.

But since you've mentioned "IE compatibility mode in Edge does not work in the application", you can reach out to Microsoft through one of the following paths:

1. [Open a support ticket](https://support.serviceshub.microsoft.com/supportforbusiness) for help with technical issues.
2. [Request help from the App Assure team](https://www.microsoft.com/fasttrack/microsoft-365/app-assure) for app compatibility issues.