# How to create file of USED css from a given webpage

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

With as all being very careful about resources within web development I am looking for a tool that you can pass a url and it show what CSS is actually used on that page but more importantly have the ability to download or extract that CSS Selectors and the actual css to create a single css of only the css needed to render that page, I have tried DustMe and various plugins. I realized I am not using 89% of bootstrap for example but picking it apart is almost impossible on pre built sites.

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I extract only the used CSS on a given web page and have that combined into a separate style sheet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24665885/how-can-i-extract-only-the-used-css-on-a-given-web-page-and-have-that-combined-i)

Comment: While I accept this is similar, I am on windows platform and do not have node. thanks. sorry if I have missed something.

Answer (score 0):

[uncss.io](http://uncss.io/) works pretty well. Just enter your page URL and it will give you the cleaned CSS. It works for me on some pages, but not other pages.

REF: [unused-css](https://unused-css.com/) - (Paid Service)

or  [CSS Trashman](https://github.com/begriffs/css-ratiocinator)

*EDIT:*

Use [uncss git](https://github.com/giakki/uncss) which requires *node.js*. It can be added to your built-in scripts to remove the unused css.

Comment: uncss.io seems to be a dead link

Answer (score 0):

There is a online tool which provides that service, its not free though, [unused-css.com](https://unused-css.com/)

I'd recommend [using uncss](https://github.com/giakki/uncss) (requires node).
It can be added to your grunt build scripts to remove the css your are not using and is easy to configure