# How can I tell if all my style sheets are in use on my website?

Tags: css

Have over 100 Style Sheets on a large website maintained by many people, how can I tell if all of the style sheets are still being used by pages on my site?

Comment: Sounds like you'd need to parse the server logs.

Comment: You can use https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/css-usage/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use one off tools [to get the list of styles that are not being used from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361007/is-there-a-way-to-check-which-css-styles-are-being-used-or-not-used-on-a-web-pag).
Then you would need to write css file class reader (or regex) that would take that list of unused styles and check each css file.
If all styles in some file would have a match in unused list - add file name to list of unused css files.

Comment: So if my site has 1000 pages I need to check each one individually? Come on, we can do better than that, can't we?