# CSS:: Is there any CSS element inspector (or plugin)?

Tags: html, css, firefox, plugins, xpi

I was wondering if there is a CSS element inspector so you can easily copy an element completely **AND** all it's (**USED ONLY**) CSS properties.

I want to be able to copy only the CSS lines that used to create that specific [selected] element.

iow... I want to clean all lines that was NOT used for used to create [maybe] other element(s) without the need to work hard and search inside the CSS file(s) manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

right-click -> inspect element -> **Computed**

Comment: I know that... I do not want necessarily to return all original CSS line(s) and all it's propertie(s) (like for example there is many CSS reset files that all of them using margin:0;padding:0; and if that have been used to create my element I still need to clean the css reset file). I want to get only the lines that was used to create that element (so the plugin will make the hard cleaning work for me).

Comment: The computed tab gives you all of the current styles after all the calculations and overrides have been applied.  So you wouldn't have all of the redundant styles.  In Chrome you can highlight and copy the whole set.

Comment: I'm in love with Firefox but If Google chrome is the answer so I will give it a try :-)

Comment: You can do the same in Firefox.  Right-click the element, choose "Inspect Element", then in the inspector you will see an option for "Computed" (next to "Rules", which is the default)

Answer (score 2):

You could link your project in the Chrome Dev Tools. This way you can do live edits.  [enter link description here](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/workspaces)

Answer (score 1):

I found this question.

[Is there a way to check which CSS styles are being used or not used on a web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361007/is-there-a-way-to-check-which-css-styles-are-being-used-or-not-used-on-a-web-pag)

This points to a [Firefox plugin](http://CSS%20Usage) and a [Chrome plugin](http://meeech.amihod.com/very-useful-find-unused-css-rules-with-google/) that you allow you to see only the applied styles.