# Which CSS classes is using a specified HTML page out of 20 pages

Tags: html, css, compare

For first, I'm really sorry for my English.

My question:
Let's say you code a few HTML pages with one CSS file.
Now, not every HTML page uses everything out of the CSS file.
How can I see what a specified page is using out of the CSS in the easiest way?

The purpose:
I have a CSS file with more than 4500 lines. Instead to search the whole HTML for the CSS classes etc. and remove them, I'd like to see everything that this page is using - So, everything in CSS, what is not needed, to delete.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is-there-a-way-to-check-which-css-styles-are-being-used-or-not-used-on-a-web-pag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361007/is-there-a-way-to-check-which-css-styles-are-being-used-or-not-used-on-a-web-pag)

Comment: Well, you could work out which pages use which styles and link to different sheets, but it sounds like a nightmare. CSS is read and styles added to the HTML pretty quickly - so a 4500 line file doesn't sound that bad (unless, is this minified?!). There are more important steps you can take to improve performance, e.g. reduce HTTP requests, parallel downloads, etc.

Comment: If you want to check step by step you should inspect element and see what css files is your page using: http://prntscr.com/8muk4j
Also, you can take a look on this thread: http://addyosmani.com/blog/removing-unused-css/

Comment: The problem is not the performance. It's because I included the HTML in another page, so the other page is using the 4500-lines CSS also which modifies a lot of things.

Comment: Dejan Munjiza, Thank you. Simply I can remove the unused CSS first and then to search everything one-by-one :)