# Get all CSS class selectors used in code, which doesn't have CSS ruleset defined

Tags: css, css-selectors

How to list all the CSS classes that I have used throughout my code, which **DO NOT HAVE "CSS ruleset" defined for it**?

Something like

```css
/*Definition (or Rule set) for .some-random-class 
doesn't exist or is commented out like below

.some-random-class {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

*/

.known-class {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="some-random-class">
  <span class="known-class"/>
</div>
```

I'm expecting something like `getAllUndeclaredCSS()` to return `['some-random-class']` as the answer.

---

**Update 1**: This is not same as "Checking which CSS Styles are being used", since the definitions doesn't exist, but the usage exists

**Update 2**: I have initial answer to help me get started. Doesn't work in all cases, but works to some extent.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to check which CSS styles are being used or not used on a web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361007/is-there-a-way-to-check-which-css-styles-are-being-used-or-not-used-on-a-web-pag)

Comment: I am looking for the opposite of that. I do not have CSS classes defined (because I removed old libraries), my code is using it. I need a way to find out missing definitions.

Comment: How can I reword the question, to make it clear?

Comment: This may be a tedious method if you have lots of pages but it may still prove useful - 
if your using Chrome you can press `Ctrl + Shift + P` and search for `show coverage` this will show you how many of your styles are being used across this particular page

Comment: The CSS ruleset doesn't exist for some of the classes I have used. I'm pretty sure those won't show up in Chrome coverage.

Comment: This is a valid question related to CSS usage. I am not asking for any book, software library or a plug-in. Nor it is a request for tutorial.

Comment: @Aftab you want a JavaScript solution or something else?

Comment: @SalmanA Anything would work. Your answer has given me couple of hints. I will try to tweak it to give me what I want.

Comment: Closed as what? Apparently CSS questions are restricted to questions such as how do i draw a flower with 11 petals using CSS and are well received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me!

```js
let elementsWithClass = document.querySelectorAll("[class]");
let classNames = new Set();
elementsWithClass.forEach(node =>
    node.classList.forEach(item => classNames.add(item))
);

let stylesheets = document.styleSheets;
let definitionsFound = new Set();
for (i = 0; i < stylesheets.length; i++) {
    rules = stylesheets[i].cssRules;
    for (j = 0; j < rules.length; j++) {
        if (rules[j].type === CSSRule.STYLE_RULE) {
            let match = rules[j].selectorText.match(/\.[^\.: ]+?(?=\.| |$|:)/g);
            match && match.forEach(item => definitionsFound.add(item.replace(".", "")));
        }
    }
}

let missingDefs = [];
classNames.forEach(item => {
    if (!definitionsFound.has(item)) {
        missingDefs.push(item);
    }
});
console.log(missingDefs);
```

Run this after opening your site! You will get to know list of CSS rules which has missing css rules. Thanks for the tip, @SalmanA

PS: If you are running an older browser which doesn't support `Set` change it to array and filter out the duplicates.

Answer (score -3):

Give this a try

```
:not([class])
```

This will just select all of the classes that have no css classes assigned to them.

Comment: This will give me all the elements with no classname given to it. I think you misunderstood the question.

Comment: How can I reword the question, to make it clear?

Comment: Crap, im sorry to be of no use. I hope you'll find your answer very soon